# Calling a Javascript function inside a DIV from another DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function displayImages() to display all the images in a  directory.
I am calling this function inside a DIV "photo_gallery" so that the images display in that DIV only (after page loads)

However I also needs to display the image gallery dynamically and for which I have to call this function from outside DIV i:e from other function inside my js file.

```
<div id="photo_gallery" style="display:none">
  <ul>
    <script>displayImages();</script>
</ul>

</div>
```

Can someone please advise

Below is my function :

Note : (here images is an array of images)

```
function displayImages() {

 for (i=0;i<images.length;i++) {

  document.write("<a href='#pop1'>");

   document.write("<img onclick='currentimage(&quot;" + images[i] + "&quot;)'    class='photo'  src='" + images[i] + "' width='160' height='120'/>");
 document.write("</a>");


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute the javascript-function in the body onload event or in a script tag outside your div-container.

```
<body onLoad="displayImages()">
```

In your function displayImages() you have to set the innerHTML (content) of the Div-Container f.ex.:

```
yourHtmlGalleryGeneratedContent = '';
for (i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
 yourHtmlGalleryGeneratedContent += "<a href='#pop1'>";
 [...]
}
document.getElementById('photo_gallery').innerHTML = yourHtmlGalleryGeneratedContent;
```